creating an automation from Fillezila to SFMC using Automation Studio
I was creating an automation from Fillezila to SFMC using Automation Studio. The csv was in the Subpast called scheduler(as you can see at the screenshot attached).
When a run the automation studio it did not find the file, so a did another test looking for the same fille, but in the past IMPORT and is worked well.
How can i solve it to find the csv at the subpast SCHEDULER?

I am not sure I understand the details of your questions. It also does not have any screenshots attached. Assuming following:

Your automation is able to pick up the file in Import folder, but not
in the Scheduler subfolder

What you need to observe, is your File Drop trigger should be pointed to your Scheduler folder (as per the configuration option below).

Prior to adding the File Import activity to your automation, you will need to create a File Location in Setup, which will point to subfolder of your Enhanced FTP:

This will ensure you will both trigger the automation, and pick up the file from the right location. I will also suggest using %%BASEFILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%.csv for the filename in your import activity to avoid issues with .filepart when importing large files. I write more about this solution in this thread here on SFSE.
